# htaccess Regular expression allow "-" and letters

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This is my regular expression on my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?m=post&id=$2&cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

but when i try to enter to this url I get 404 page not found.

site.com/movies-tv/119284/movie-brscreener-hq-thriller.html

I need to allow "-" at movies-tv

Comment: `(.*)` matches everything, including a `-`. Something else is causing your 404.

Comment: yes but I dont need to allow numbers :S, that expression allow all

Comment: Your regular expression *is* `(.*)`, that will already match the `-` character, you don't need to change it in order to match it, *something else is broken*.

Comment: As I said, (.*) allows numbers, and I don't need allow numbers in my slug